# StreamWriter Problem - 2 Spaces Written as Hex '20 c2 a0' instead of Hex '20 20'

Tags: c#

I'm writing a bunch of strings to a file using a string writer but I've discovered a problem when I look at the file created in hex, and that is that one of the spaces (x20) is replaced with a non-breaking space instead (xc2 a0) when there are 2 spaces separating words.  I don't know if this is a big deal but I would like to know if there is an easy resolution to this?

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
20 c2 a0 53 57 45 45 50 Dump = "  SWEEP"
```

But I would like it to always be:

```
20 20 53 57 45 45 50    Dump = "  SWEEP"
```

Note that the c2 a0 aren't visible here but the dump looks something like 'A.' when I use the Notepad++ Hex Plugin.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers and Thanks In Advance;

-Daver

Comment: I tried and got the expected result... could you post your code ? Also, where does the string come from ?

Comment: I would assume the source contains a non-breaking space. You could replace them before writing. Where do you get your source from?

Comment: That's fast.  The source is:

                //Transaction #1.
            Transaction transaction1 = InitializeTransaction(_tranId1, TransactionProcessing.Currency.CurrencyCode.CAD,
                                                             transactionDate,
                                                             (decimal) 24939.34, @"CIBC  SWEEP".ToString(), "3");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your source contains non-breaking spaces you can replace them before writing out the string.

```
string sourceString = ..some string...
sourceString = sourceString.Replace((char)160, ' '); //replace nobr with space
```

Comment: Brilliant!  You did it.  Free coffee for you whenever you're in Canada.